# When creating new data.frame column, what is the difference between `df$NewCol=` and `df[,"NewCol"]=` methods?

Tags: r

Using the default "iris" DataFrame in R, how come when creating a new column "NewCol"

```
iris[,'NewCol'] = as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date()) # throws Warning
```

BUT

```
iris$NewCol = as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date()) # is correct
```

This issue doesn't exist when assigning Primitive types like chr, int, float, ....

Comment: What is the question? You are aware that `as.POSIXlt()` is returning a list?

Comment: Why should that make any difference ? Both the assignment create new column of data frame. If it throw warning for one, then it should for the other as well right .

Comment: There is a subtle difference. If you want an explanation of the difference then you should modify your post.

Comment: Sure, done ....

Answer (score 0):

First, notice as @sindri_baldur pointed, `as.POSIXlt` returns a list.
From R help ($<-.data.frame):

> There is no data.frame method for $, so x$name uses the default method which treats x as a list (with partial matching of column names if the match is unique, see Extract). The replacement method (for $) checks value for the correct number of rows, and replicates it if necessary.

So, if You try `iris[, "NewCol"] <- as.POSIClt(Sys.Date())` You get warning that You're trying assign a list object to a vector. So only the first element of the list is used.

Again, from R help:

"For [ the replacement value can be a list: each element of the list is used to replace (part of) one column, recycling the list as necessary".

And in Your case, only one column is specified meaning only the first element of the `as.POSIXlt`'s result (list) will be used. And You are warned of that.

Using `$` syntax the iris data.frame is treated as a list and then the result of `as.POSIXlt` - a list again - is appended to it. Finally, the result is data.frame, but take a look at the type of the NewCol - it's a list.

```
iris[, "NewCol"] <- as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date()) # warning
iris$NewCol2 <- as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date())

typeof(iris$NewCol) # double
typeof(iris$NewCol2) # list
```

Suggestion: maybe You wanted to use `as.POSIXct()`?